# Downloding blob from azure storage taking too much time

Tags: python, base64, azure-blob-storage, blob, azure-storage

I am converting image to **base64** and then uploading that base64 string object to **azure blob storage**.
The issue I'm facing while downloading that blob from object. My max image size is 1 MB. when I convert 877 KB image to base64 string Size : It gives me **1170488 chars** long string.

So when I download those 877 KB from azure storage it takes around 15 - 20 seconds. and in that time server gives 500 error.

```
def get_blob_with_name(container_name, blob_name):
    """
    Function for downloading blob from the azure
    """
    start = timer()
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(settings.CONNECT_STR)
    blob_client_instance = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container_name, blob_name, snapshot=None)
    blob_data = blob_client_instance.download_blob()
    data = blob_data.readall()
    end = timer()
    print("Time taken for downloading blob: ", end - start)
    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

> when I download those 877 KB from azure storage it takes around 15 -20 seconds. and in that time server gives 500 error.

The Error 503 (Server Busy) or 500 (Timeout) Error occurs when Azure storage is unable to handle a request due to

1. **Transient issue**
   Like Connectivity Failure, Service Unavailability, Platform Issue. Or

2. This error might also occur when your scaling targets are not met, and you reach your throttling limits.

As a resolution- Multiple retries of the operation can work, also this transient issue might occur due to some configuration missing in your code.

I have tried below code and tried downloading an Image above 1MB And was able to download the Image successfully with your code. But instead of using timer function, I used **`time.time`**  and got time taken for download which was below 10 seconds.

**Code:**

```
from  azure.storage.blob  import  BlobServiceClient

import  time

def  get_blob_with_name():

 CONNECT_STR="<your storage connect string>"
 container_name="test"
 blob_name="demo1mbimage.jpg"
 start = time.time()
 blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(CONNECT_STR)
 blob_client_instance = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container_name, blob_name, snapshot=None)
 with  open("demo1mbimage.jpg", 'wb') as  file: 
  data = blob_client_instance.download_blob()
   file.write(data.readall())
 end=time.time()
 print("Time taken for downloading blob for : ", end - start)
  return  data
get_blob_with_name()
```

**Console:**
[image]

**Image:**

You can see the time taken to download the image and also size of the image too in bottom.

[image]

**Reference:**
[Performance and scalability checklist for Blob storage - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-performance-checklist#timeout-and-server-busy-errors)